# zuul add extra prefix for each eureka service ids

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, zuul-testing

Currently I have hardcoded my IP in zuul properties files

```
zuul.routes.userdomain.path=/oldusers/**
zuul.routes.userdomain.url=http://olduser_server_ip:4545/oldusers/v1/oldlist
```

Now I have added Eureka and enabled Service discovery in zuul, now I  want to configure like below

```
zuul.routes.userdomain.path=/oldusers/**
zuul.routes.userdomain.serviceId=OLD-USER-SERVICE
```

but in this how to add extra prefix **'v1/oldlist'** ?

I can not use zuul.prefix because,  I have some more services with different prefixes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add prefix like

```
zuul.prefix="v1"
```

And you can stripe the prefix for specific service like

```
zuul.routes.userdomain.stripPrefix=true
```

Comment: In my requirement I have to append extra prefix or based on the in coming url route to.different url